# How to attach a .dae file to exsisting rigged model?

Tags: makehuman

Import MakeHuman figure direct into Blender 3.4.1.
Join seperate parts.
Apply all transforms.
Parent rig to figure.
Pose mode, everything works as should.
Add flat cap as a .dae Collada file.
join it to the original figure.
Problem, it does want to move with the rig.

I have also tried joining it using Boolean but it still fails.

[Test Man File](https://workupload.com/file/S5eaMWEaNV8)

[image: Flat cap joined]

[image: No its not]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the cap with <kbd>L</kbd> and assign the vertices to the vertex group called *Head* so that it will be controlled by the bone called *Head*:

[image]

Comment: Thanks once again, so helpful, big thumbs up.